# How to create a dynamic web project with gradle eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I want to easily (yes, i hate command lines) make a project that can be exported as a WAR file to a server containing an application i built using gradle.

My current approach is Creating a Dynamic Web Project and drag and dropping all the libraries in the lib folder.

There must be a better way!!!

Comment: What is this application you built with gradle? Isn't it precisely the application to deploy on the server?

Comment: Switch to Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Im not paying a fortune monthly just to use gradle in my web projects @Jared Rummler

Comment: use Ant for your build and Ivy to manage your dependencies